# What will be the additive inverse of the following question?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, axioms

In the Following Question:
The set of all ordered triples of real numbers with the
operations

$(x, y, z) (+) (x', y', z') = (x +x' , y + y', z + z')$

$r(*)(x, y ,z)=(x,1,z)$

Now Since the addition is standard addition, it should follow all the addition axioms. But I can't seem to figure out it's  additive inverse.

I found the additive identity as (0,0,0)

But when I take additive inverse of $V = (x,y,z)$

$-V = (x,1,z)$ according to the multiplication given; adding it to $V$ gives result of $(2x,2,2z)$ which is not equal to additive identity.

P.S $(+)$ and $(*)$ represents vector addition and Vector Multiplication, I  didn't know how to format them and I know that it doesn't form the vector space per se multiplication axioms but I still want to know how to find it's additive inverse.
Thank you

Comment: Multiplicative inverse is not the same as additive inverse.

Comment: @Paul is right. Identities for the operations will differ too. Also, have you checked distributivity?

Comment: @Paul Correct me if I am wrong but as far as I understood, additive inverse is the value that you add in matrix that results in additive identity right?

Comment: @J.G. Could you please explain how will they be different?
I did check and it doesn't form vector space even with 1.v property But Iam just learning about finding additive identity

Comment: That's right, so the additive inverse $-V=(-x,-y,-z)$

Comment: @Paul Does that mean it's not necessary for additive inverse to be found by multiplying by -1?
You just have to find the set that when added gives additive identity? 
And that set SHOULD belong to the given condition?

Comment: The only requirement of the additive inverse is that it should satsify $V + -V = 0$.

Comment: Where $-V$ represents additive inverse not necessarily the vector multiplied by -1?
And 0 is additive identity not necessarily a null vector or 0?

Comment: In this case $-V \neq -1 *V$.

Comment: "Could you please explain how will they be different?" For an easier example take normal arithmetic on reals so the identities are $0,\,1$, while the inverses are $-x,\,1/x$ (the latter defined iff $x\ne0$).